# Python Concurrent.Futures Map not executing concurrently

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I have the following example:

```
import time
import concurrent.futures
x = [10, 1, 2]

def sleeper(secs):
    time.sleep(secs)
    print('I slept for {} seconds'.format(secs))

# returns in the order given
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    for future in executor.map(sleeper, x):
        future
```

I would expect that this function will print "I slept for {} seconds" in order that of each sleeping, however, ALL the results are printed after the last value (10) is processed.

Why is this occurring and how would I print sleeper as each call completes

Comment: Does [`sys.stdout.flush()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/230751/190597) fix the problem? (By the way, when I run your code, the print statements are printed one at a time. So I'm thinking the problem might not be in the Python code but in how the terminal or IDE is buffering the output.)

Comment: I am in an ipython notebook so that might be the case

Answer (score 0):

I tested with Python2 and 3 in terminal, it works as expected. With IPython Notebook, all the results are printed after the last value (10) is processed.

So it is a problem of IPython Notebook, maybe you should submit a issue.